# Refactor class based approach in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a lambda function to make a request and fetch data from API.
I am using as a class based approach which I think could refactor it and write in correct way.
May be we can change this class based approach if required. Below is the approach which I have implemented.

**app.js**

```
const  apiService = require('./apiService.js');

exports.handler = (async(event, context, callback) => {
    
    if ((event["type"]) && event["type"] != "" ){
      let apiServices = new apiService(event["type"], context);
      let successResponse = await apiServices.beginProcess();  
      let response = return {
        'body': JSON.stringify(successResponse),
        'statusCode': 200
      };
    } else {
       response = {
        'body':"invalid request",
        'statusCode': 200
      };
      return response
    }
});
```

**apiService.js**

```
const getCredentialsService = require('./modules/getCredentials')
let getCredentials = new getCredentialsService();

class apiService {
    constructor(eventType, event, context) {
        this.event = event;
        this.context = context;
    }

    beginProcess() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          if (this.event["type"] == "getcredentials") {
                let credentialsData = await this.fetchCredentials();
                resolve(credentialsData);
            }
        });
    }
    
    fetchCredentials() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
             let response = await getCredentials.getCredentialsData(this.event);
             resolve(response);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = apiService;
```

**getCredentials.js**

```
var request = require('request');
var moment = require('moment');
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let sts = new AWS.STS();
class getCredentialsService {

    getCredentialsData = async (event) => {
        const data = await sts.assumeRole(params1).promise();
        const athena = new AWS.Athena({
            accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
        });

        // Next athena query exectuion
        await athena.startQueryExecution(queryParams, async function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            } else {
                var QueryExecutionId = data["QueryExecutionId"];
                const data1 = await getQueryResult(QueryExecutionId, data)
                resolve(data1);
            }
        });

    };
}

module.exports = getCredentials;
```

Comment: remove apiService.js entirely and turn getCredentialsData() into a async function outside of any class